# How to Install Pulsecaster? Python install not working

Tags: software-installation, python, tar

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am trying to install the software http://stickster.github.io/pulsecaster/

It comes in a tar.gz file which I have downloaded and extracted to a folder. Instructions on the internet say that in order to install this I should go into the folder on the terminal and type "python3 setup.py build" to activate the setup.py folder. However this comes up as 'command not found' on the terminal. Python is installed on the computer.

~/Downloads/stickster-pulsecaster-c0b3a20$ $ python setup.py build
$: command not found

Not sure what to do now?

Edit: see my solution below.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1396537/edit) the post to add the exact error message and the exact command you entered?

Comment: This is not the exact error message. Usually it is something like `bash: "command-here": command not found`. Since python3 is already installed in the system, bash should not report that it cannot python. Please edit and post the exact error message (you can copy-paste from the terminal).

Comment: ~/Downloads/stickster-pulsecaster-c0b3a20$ $ python setup.py build $: command not found

this is what I copied from the terminal exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The Python 3.X build module is provided by python3-distutils in Ubuntu 20.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-setuptools python3-distutils
```

To install Pulsecaster from source code use the handy "distutils" script that's provided as follows:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: This got things moving, but still returned a error message (a new one this time, which is progress I guess!)

python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

Comment: Ok installed setup using "sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools"

This finally allowed me to run Python setup.py build

However, when I entered Python setup.py install I needed to add Sudo to it to make it work, so sudo python setup.py install